# how to drag 2 div at the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

how to make, when first div drags, second div drag too

first div drags with jquery ui

```
<div id="draggable"  style="position: absolute; z-index: 999; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: orange;"></div>
<div id="xren" style="position: absolute; z-index: 998; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: orange;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = $('#draggable').offset();
 $('#xren').css("top", a.top + 100 + "px");
 $('#xren').css("left", a.left + 100 + "px");
```

but it does not work

[image]

first div drags with jquery ui  & second div drags when first div drags

Comment: Any reason to not just put them into a single dragable div?

Comment: @Chris Of course.. He will say yes.

Comment: @user1008575: Often there will be a good reason but if the obvious solution isn't valid then we clearly haven't got the whole question so either an obvious answer was missed or some useful details in the question were missed out. So either the question is answered or the question can be made better.

Answer (score 5):

Something like:

```
$("#div1").bind("drag", function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $("#div2").css({ left : offset.left, top: offset.top});
});
```

And the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You must set correct position attributes on div and then you can move elements.
See /2 & /0.5 this is divider which defines ratio.

HTML

```
<div id="div1">AAA</div>
<div style="position: absolute;">
    <div id="div2" style="position:relative">BBB</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#div1").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var offset = ui.offset;
        $("#div2").css({ left : offset.left /2, top: offset.top/0.5});
    }
});
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/jmav/uj6T6/